# colllection check boxes - how to change user attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have users that can choose which 'areas' they cover.

The relationship between 'users' and 'areas' is a has many and belongs to.

I can currently get collection_check_boxes to list the 'area' options for the user but I'm stuck on getting the areas to be updated once the user chooses and submits the area options.

Here's my form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= collection_check_boxes(:user, :area_ilondon_ids, AreaIlondon.all, :id, :postcode) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<%end%>
```

The form above renders a list of checkboxes showing the users current 'area' selection but when I submit the form the areas do not get updated.

Comment: What do your user_params look like?  Do you have something like this `:area_ilondon_ids[]`?  You need to let in the array of ids.  Also what do your logs say?

Comment: Thanks. I permitted :area_ilondon_ids at first. When I changed it to: params require permit:  :area_ilondon_ids=>[]  it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do your user_params look like? Do you have something like this `:area_ilondon_ids[]`? You need to let in the array of ids.

As @Stoob pointed out the following was needed:

`:area_ilondon_ids=>[]`